# Check if there is no "true" value per "id"

Tags: mysql

I need to find the domain_link_id's , which doesn't have any (is_active = true) value.

[image]

I've created following query,but this query doesn't work properly.Could you please help me to fix this query?

```
SELECT distinct domain_link_history.id,domain_link_history.domain_link_id 
FROM domain_link_history
INNER JOIN (
SELECT id,is_active 
FROM domain_link_history 
GROUP BY domain_link_id HAVING count(is_active) > 1) dlh2 
ON domain_link_history.id = dlh2.id 
where domain_link_history.is_active = false
```

Thank you in advance.

Cheers,

Comment: hmm not sure to understand...something like this ? select domain_link_id from domain_link_history where is_active = 'false'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified [Kickstart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1723545/kickstart)'s query and now it works.

```
SELECT domain_link_id, 
SUM(IF(is_active = 'true', 1, 0)) AS false_count , 
Count(is_active) as history_row_count
FROM domain_link_history
GROUP BY domain_link_id
HAVING false_count = history_row_count
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume you will need the following:

```
SELECT domain_link_id 
FROM domain_link_history
WHERE is_active <> 'true'
GROUP BY domain_link_id
```

This will give all `domain_link_id` fields, where `is_active` is not set to true. This will also only show unique `domain_link_id`, so you don't get a load of duplicates.

This is the simplest way to get the info you want providing I have understood your request

You could also alternatively use

```
SELECT domain_link_id 
FROM domain_link_history
WHERE is_active = 'false'
GROUP BY domain_link_id
```

This is just in case you have other options than simply true and false in the `is_active field`

Comment: hi Jon, Thank you for your answer.But I get the same result with your first query.I think I didn't explain it clearly.I need to see the domain_link_ids,which doesn't have ANY is_active = true value.this queries give me also the domain_link_ids,which has one "is_active = true" value-.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a left join against a sub query maybe?

```
SELECT DISTINCT domain_link_id
FROM domain_link_history a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT domain_link_id
    FROM domain_link_history
    WHERE is_active = 'true'
) sub1
ON a.domain_link_id = Sub1.domain_link_id
WHERE Sub1.domain_link_id IS NULL
```

Or an alternative using sum:-

```
SELECT domain_link_id, SUM(IF(is_active = 'true', 1, 0)) AS true_count
FROM domain_link_history
GROUP BY domain_link_id
HAVING true_count = 0
```

(neither tested)

Comment: Hi , I've modified your second query, and now it works.Thank you ;)

Comment: No problem, but not sure why you needed to mod it. Your modified version should give the same results (as far as I can see), but requires an extra aggregate function. I am probably misunderstanding something with your requirements but not sure what!.

Comment: Your second query gives me the result of the domain_links_id's, which has only is_active = true. I got 13 results with your query, with my modified query I got 126 results.

Comment: I am definitely missing something. The query should initially give a list of all the domain_link_ids with a count of how many have is_active set to true. Then the HAVING should throw away any where that count is not zero (ie, any where there was a row with is_active = true). Sorry to badger you, just trying to work out what I missed

Comment: If you want to work on that.I can send you the "Table Script" and some data.You can test it on your machine,if you would like to.

Comment: That would be great, or on SQL Fiddle if that would be easier.

Comment: Thank you. I have spotted it. Your is_active column is a bit field, where I was treating it as a char. If you remove the quotes from around true in my query it gives the results you want. Your query has the opposite issue. If you take the having query out of your query then the row for 23213 has a false_count of 0, which code wise should be a count of the rows where is_active is true, and the only row for this item has is_active set to 1. Basically IF(is_active='true', 1, 0) returns 0 if is_active is true and 1 if it is false.

Comment: yes you're right.sorry I forgot to mention,that is_active column is a bit field.I tried it without the quotes , your query worked fine.Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `SUM` with a `CASE` expression?

```
SELECT      MIN(id) AS id
            , domain_link_id
FROM        domain_link_history
GROUP BY    domain_link_id
HAVING      SUM(CASE WHEN is_active = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

You could also try using the `MIN` and `MAX` aggregates:

```
SELECT  t1.id
        , t1.domain_link_id
FROM    domain_link_history AS t1
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT      MIN(id) AS id
                        , domain_link_id
            FROM        domain_link_history
            GROUP BY    domain_link_id
            HAVING      MIN(is_active) = MAX(is_active)
        ) AS q1
            ON  q1.id = t1.id
            AND q1.domain_link_id = t1.domain_link_id
WHERE   q1.domain_link_id = false
```

The subquery above will find all records where `is_active` is entirely `false` or entirely `true`, then just pick the `false` records from the outer query